# What's the fastest way to walk through an Excel Range object backwards?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using VBA in the Excel VBE, but c# or vb are fine.
The concept should hold true across the languages.

Comment: Hey GollyJer, I was just curious of your purpose for this.

Comment: This was for inserting multiple rows between an existing list of contiguous data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what you mean. You want to go through from the bottom to top, instead of top to bottom?

This should do:

```
Dim myrange As Range
Set myrange = Range("B3:E10")

Dim row As Integer, col As Integer
For row = myrange.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
    For col = myrange.Columns.Count To 1 Step -1
        Debug.Print myrange(row, col).Value  
    Next col
Next row
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're working with ranges of more than a few cells and don't need to modify the cells, always consider pulling the values into an array and working with that: the interaction between code and worksheet is relatively (very) expensive. If you're working from a .NET assembly, that goes double (maybe triple, maybe more) because there are several more steps involved in a round trip.

In VBA, something like this:

```
Dim vals As Variant
Dim row As Long, col As Long

vals = Range("A1:Z100") ' or whatever
For col = UBound(vals,2) To LBound(vals,2) Step -1
    For row = UBound(vals) To LBound(vals) Step -1
        DoSomethingInterestingWith vals(row, col)
    Next
Next
```